# textview is not showing text

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, textview

I have created form which contain question text and input field suitable to question. I have spinner ,edittext and checkbox in my form. 
All are created dynamically using activity . Problem in the created layout is that input field displayed correctly but textview not displayed.

```
   private void  showIssueForm(){
    for (int i=0;i<claimQuestionList.size();i++){
        ClaimQuestion claimQuestion=claimQuestionList.get(i);
        LinearLayout linearLayout=ClaimUtils.createLayoutForClaimQuestion(claimQuestion,this);
        /*claimQuestionsLinearLayout.addView(linearLayout);*/
        claimQuestionsLinearLayout.addView(linearLayout,i);
    }

}   


 private static TextView createTextView(ClaimQuestion claimQuestion,Context context){                                               
 TextView textView=new TextView(context);                                                                                       
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams textViewLayoutParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300,80,1);                                        
 textView.setText("hi m printing the text what are you looking for");//claimQuestion.getOrder()+". "+claimQuestion.getLabel()); 
 textView.setLayoutParams(textViewLayoutParams);                                                                                
 //textView.setMinLines(1);                                                                                                     
// textView.setSingleLine(false);                                                                                               
 textView.setTextSize(R.dimen.system12);                                                                                        
 textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                                                                                          
 textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.light_white_));                                                  
 return textView;
```

}

The linear layout where i added form element is given below

```
  public static LinearLayout createLayoutForClaimQuestion(ClaimQuestion claimQuestion,Context context){   
 LinearLayout linearLayout=new LinearLayout(context);                                                
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500,200);                
 linearLayout.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutParams);                                                   
 linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);                                                 
 TextView questionLabel=createTextView(claimQuestion,context);                                       
 linearLayout.addView(questionLabel,0);                                                              
 if (claimQuestion.getQuestionType()==ClaimQuestion.QuestionTypeEnum.CQ_TEXT){                       
     EditText editText=createEditText(claimQuestion,context);                                        
     linearLayout.addView(editText,1);                                                               
 }else if(claimQuestion.getQuestionType()==ClaimQuestion.QuestionTypeEnum.CQ_CHECKBOX){              
     CheckBox checkBox=createCheckBox(claimQuestion,context);                                        
     linearLayout.addView(checkBox,1);                                                               
 }else if(claimQuestion.getQuestionType()==ClaimQuestion.QuestionTypeEnum.CQ_SELECT){                
     Spinner spinner=createSpinner(claimQuestion,context);                                           
     linearLayout.addView(spinner,1);                                                                
 }                                                                                                   
 return linearLayout;
```

}

The xml layout file for the parent layout is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.maximus.mycar.VehicleSelectActivity"
android:background="@drawable/bluebg_320_568">
<include layout="@layout/header"
    android:id="@+id/top_header_layout_ici"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/claim_questions_scroll_view"
    android:layout_below="@id/top_header_layout_ici"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/claim_questions_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: change color of text to black

Comment: where you are adding `textView` ?

Comment: @AmolTate i have tried but it didn't work.

Comment: @Rustam in linearlayout whose parent is linearlayout and whose parent is scrollview

Comment: definition of `createTextView(...)`

Comment: Check orientation of parent layout

Comment: @Rustam textview taking the appropriate width and height but text is not displaying.

Comment: Which color you are using now?

Comment: I checked the same and it is working for me

Comment: @Rustam this same problem occuring with edit text .In which text doesn't display when i type .

Comment: Try to change app theme

Comment: just for test do this `textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);` and check

Comment: Just change your app theme to Holo.light

Comment: @Rustam red color is also not working.

Comment: You tried with changing app theme?

Comment: @AmolTate yes i tried just but not working

Comment: can you show us full code or screenshots of the code

Comment: `claimQuestionsLinearLayout` is main container layout in your layout.xml right?

Comment: @Rustam no scroll view ..you can check in posted xml with id claim_questions_scroll_view

Comment: Why you are not using this? LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.claim_questions_linear_layout)

Comment: @AmolTate i used this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Changed the font size by setting fixed value then it worked fine.

```
textView.setTextSize(12);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this one:-

```
 textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_white_));
```

instead of this:-

```
 textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.light_white_));
```

please let me know if it works or not :)

Comment: i am not doing this in activity  .